# FB API /me/friends "Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when using friends array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's the code that's throwing the above error:

```
    $friend_json = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    $friends = array();
    foreach($friend_json->data as $friend) {
        $friends[] = $friend->name;
    }
    $friend_list = json_encode($friends);
```

I know this code work's as it wasn't throwing this error when I was doing the same query but when using the direct Graph API URL with `file_get_contents();`. The SDK has been installed correctly as it's being used to pull user data successfully in the same script.

Comment: Are you sure you have friends? :P  Sorry, couldn't resist. Try `var_dump($friends_json);` and check what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite `$user_friends` being an array of an array, which in PHP as far as I'm aware is treated as an object, it didn't like me using `'->'` to access it's sub array, so instead I used square brackets. Thank's for your help though.

Working code:
    $friend_list = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

```
$friends = array();
foreach($friend_list['data'] as $friend) {
    $friends[] = $friend['name'];
}
$friend_list = json_encode($friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from `Facebook::api` is `Array`:

```
foreach($friend_json['data'] as $friend) {
  $friends[] = $friend->name;
}
```

It's also better to add simple check for errors.

```
if ($friend_json && isset($friend_json['data'])
  foreach($friend_json['data'] as $friend) {
    $friends[] = $friend->name;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friends_details = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=<your access token>']), true);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($friends_details);$i++){
   $friends_name[] = $friends_details['data'][$i]['name'];
}
```